# Create a table which contains sum of values in a column of another table using Query

Tags: sql, sqlite

This is my SQLite Table1:

```
SN       Date            ID    Value
0   05/15/2022 23:50    9761    433
1   05/20/2022 23:50    9761    440
2   05/16/2022 23:50    9761    0
3   05/13/2022 23:50    9761    0
4   05/19/2022 23:50    9761    0
5   05/15/2022 23:50    10290   376
6   05/20/2022 23:50    10290   323
7   05/14/2022 23:50    10290   324
8   05/11/2022 23:50    10290   0
9   05/16/2022 23:50    10290   0
10  05/19/2022 23:50    9988    401
11  05/15/2022 23:50    9988    224
12  05/11/2022 23:50    9988    0
13  05/10/2022 23:50    9988    175
14  05/20/2022 23:50    9988    0
```

I need to create an another table which contains cumulative sum of 'Value' column of table1 before May 15 2022 (05/15/2022 00:00) with respect to 'ID'.
I tried the below but failed:

```
CREATE TABLE table2( Date varchar(100), ID varchar(50), Value INT)

UPDATE [table2]
SET ([Date],[ID],[Value]) = ([table1].[Date],[table1].[ID],sum([table1].[Value])

FROM [table1]
WHERE [table1].[Date] < date('2022-05-15') and
GROUP BY [table1].[ID]
```

The expected output is given below.

Table2:

```
SN        Date           ID   Value
0   05/15/2022 00:00    9761    0
1   05/15/2022 00:00    10290   324
2   05/15/2022 00:00    9988    175
```

In Table2, Date column is same which indicates cumulative is calculated till May 15.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: `mysql` <> `sqlite`

Comment: Solution for sqlite

Comment: sqlite version? Have you tried writing a query; `sqlite` does support creating tables with `select` statements.

Comment: I am using Sqlite3. I am trying to get the solution from yesterday Sir! And yes sqlite3 will support creating table using Select statement.

Comment: [Edit] the question to add query you've come up with so far.

Comment: @जलजनक Edited accordingly Sir!

Comment: The format of your dates is not comparable. Change to: YYYY-MM-DD

Comment: @forpas I changed that too but something wrong with the query.

Answer (score 0):

First create the new table with proper data types (there is no `VARCHAR` [data type in SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)):

```
CREATE TABLE table2(Date TEXT, ID TEXT, Value INTEGER);
```

Then change the format of your dates in the column `Date` of `table1` to `YYYY-MM-DD` so that the dates are comparable.

Finally, use an `INSERT` (not `UPDATE`) statement:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (Date, ID, Value)
SELECT date(Date), ID, SUM(Value)
FROM table1 
WHERE date(Date) < '2022-05-15'
GROUP BY date(Date), ID;
```

Or, create the new table and insert the rows in a single statement:

```
CREATE TABLE table2 AS
SELECT date(Date) AS Date, ID, SUM(Value) AS Value
FROM table1 
WHERE date(Date) < '2022-05-15'
GROUP BY date(Date), ID;
```